# Is there a way to query usage and pricing in real time for services used by the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

I am developing applications through the Google Cloud platform. I am using multiple services included in the Google Cloud Platform at the same time. I would like to display the usage and the fee in real time on the admin page of the application I am creating. However, I do not think there is a feature for developers that provide the functionality I want, including Google's billing API. Is there a way to query usage and pricing in real time (and API programmatically) for services used by the Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 4):

I am reasonably sure there is no way to get real-time billing data for GCP projects. The API doesn't provide a real-time query, and billing exports, either to a file or to BigQuery are not up to date--some usage can be a couple of days behind. I run on-demand Data Studio billing reports on my accounts against BigQuery and the last two days are always incomplete. I believe that there is a reason Google doesn't provide account invoices for a couple of days after the month ends, which is that they don't actually know the totals until then.

If you really wanted this, depending on what you were doing, you might be able to get closer to real time by grabbing the relevant metrics from Stackdriver and calculating the costs from those, but note that based on my experience the Stackdriver metrics aren't always up to date either--for instance the cloud storage metrics can be several hours behind, but not consistently, so it is likely your calculations would still be inaccurate. I haven't looked as closely at the other metrics, so stuff like network traffic might be better.

Comment: Do you know if still there isn't a way to get GCP real time services costs using an API?
Thank you

Comment: I can confirm, there is not as of now - March, 2024