# Get realtime VideoIntelligence API usage in minutes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

How can I see the near real time minutes of usage for VideoIntelligence API features?

If I look in GCP Billing, I can see the minutes of usage for each SKU. For example:

```
SKU: Label Detection
Usage: 59.5 minutes
```

However, these metrics only appear the next day.

Does this metric appear elsewhere with a more real time value or can it somehow be calculated?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to get the minutes usage in real time as of now. The only real time data that could be tracked for Video Intelligence API is the number of request sent, request latency, etc. This data can be monitored in Cloud Console > APIs & Services > Cloud Video Intelligence API. What I could suggest is to create a feature request in http://issuetracker.google.com/.

Comment: Could the above metrics be used along with the pricing data to calculate in real-time? The billing happens on a minute basis, if we can get a metric of the ongoing minutes. It would be possible to compute an approximate real-time pricing. Are there such metrics?

Comment: @AnirudhM For me, billing does not appear to update by the minute.

Comment: @AnirudhM, this thread should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361880/7031308